# How can I do a de-facto upsert using Python's SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy's `Session.merge()` on an object whose "uniqueness" is determined by a column other than the primary key?

For example, a table of blog posts has an auto generated `id` column and a column called `url`. I'd like to `.merge()` and only insert if the URL doesn't exist in the table. (Yes, I suppose I could use a natural key rather than a surrogate key, but I don't do that anywhere else and I'd prefer not to here.)

Comment: This is more an opinion than an answer: I would not use it, even it might be possible. I'm sure you've read [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#merging), the purpose of `merge` is very different to what you are proposing. I would just use a unique index on the URL field, or maybe a programmatic check that it is unique. And yes, you should keep the surrogate key if that makes sense in you primary key strategy; besides, I don't think is a good idea to use a URL as a primary key. Hope it helps in any way.